# How to fetch and show these data in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have question table and subject table and question table contain subject wise questions for online examination.

I need to fetch subject wise questions with subject name as header and show all the questions in subject wise serial number such as example: Maths: Q1, Q2, Q3
English: Q1, Q2, Q3 and so on.
How to achieve it in php and mysql. The question table and subject table are given below.

[image: Question Table]

[image: Subject table]

Question sample data are given below

[image: Question sample]

[image]

```
<?php 
  require_once 'config.php'; 
  //$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name");
  $query1 = "SELECT q.q_id,q.setq_no, q.qtext_eng, s.sub_id, s.sub_name
  FROM question q
  INNER JOIN subject s ON s.sub_id = q.sub_id
  INNER JOIN questionset qs ON qs.qset_id = q.qset_id
  WHERE qs.qset_id =2 ORDER BY s.sub_id";
  ?>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Q.No</th>
  <th>Q Set number</th>
  <th>Q text eng</th>
</tr>
```

```
 <?php
$result1 = mysqli_query($link,$query1);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
 {
 $subID = $row1['sub_id'];
  $subName = $row1['sub_name'];
  ?>
  <h2><?php echo "$subName" ?></h2>

<?php
  error_reporting(0);


    $sno++;
    $qSet = $row1['setq_no'];
    $qEng = $row1['qtext_eng'];

?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $sno; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $qSet; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $qEng; ?></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
     <?php
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Please post some minimalistic textual sample data, expected output and what you've tried so far

Comment: and accept answers that solved your other questions that were solved

Comment: Well, show your code, have you tried anything yet. Here you can only get help you If you have tried anything.

Comment: I don't have idea how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i fetch data from database in php using mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827380/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-database-in-php-using-mysql)

Comment: Too long. Readers' eye will be exhausted, and hardly recognize what you want actually. Please minimize your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am including some of your columns from `question` table here , you can add the rest same way

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name");

$query1 = "SELECT q.q_id,q.setq_no, q.qtext_eng, s.sub_id, s.sub_name
FROM question q
INNER JOIN subject s ON s.sub_id = q.sub_id
INNER JOIN questionset qs ON qs.qset_id = q.qset_id
WHERE qs.qset_id =2 ORDER BY s.sub_id";

$presubID = 0;

<table class="table table-bordered">
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
  $subID = $row1['sub_id'];
  if($subID != $presubID){
    $subName = $row1['sub_name'];
    <h2><?php echo "$subName" ?></h2>
    $sno=0;

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Q.No</th>
          <th>Q Set</th>
          <th>Q text eng</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  }
  $presubID = $subID;

  $sno++;
  $qSet = $row1['setq_no'];
  $qEng = $row1['qtext_eng'];

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $sno; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $qSet; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $qEng; ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php
  }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: How can I fetch in a single mysqli query using inner join

Comment: you should not in your case , because then the outer while loop will be useless and you'd have to run five separate joint queries on separate subjects. but anyways here's a good example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner

Comment: Just like you gave me the code. I run it exactly found what I needed but I need to achieve this in a single query. and I need to show subject name single time but when I use inner join and I run the code subject name repeated times the question

Comment: I run this code but got subject name repeated
SELECT q.q_id,q.setq_no, q.qtext_eng, s.sub_id, s.sub_name as ss
FROM question q
INNER JOIN subject s ON s.sub_id = q.sub_id
INNER JOIN questionset qs ON qs.qset_id = q.qset_id
WHERE qs.qset_id =2

Comment: where did you add this query. can you take a screenshot of the code and post it on http://tinypic.com/

Comment: try removing the outer while loop

Comment: I removed the outer while loop and shown using php but subject name is repeated on every question display

Comment: Can you post pic of your page output and code for the page (like I gave in my answer) too. and give me some time to po=rocess those, thanks

Comment: ok can you give me some time and your inner join query was giving you correct result, right , the only problem is displaying right?